# How to set selection for treeviewer without firing selectionChanged()?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, treeviewer

I am working on an eclipse RCP project. It has several views with `TreeViewer` and I use `selectionChanged()` method to handle selection events. However, at times I need to set selection programmatically.For this, in `selectionChanged()` method, I invoke `setSelection()` method of `TreeViewer` to set the desired selection. This method fires `selectionChanged()` method of all views thus resulting in cyclic calls to `selectionChanged()`.

How can I select an item from the `TreeViewer` or `StructuredViewer` without firing `selectionChanged()` for other views?

Comment: Any feedback to my answer?

Comment: @Baz Good to know there are people facing similar problems. I thought I am doing something wrong. I have used similar structure in my application. Since it has many views handling selections using booleans becomes quite unmanageable. Eclipse should take a note of this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, creating an event that triggers the `Listener` you're currently in is always a tricky situation. What I usually do is something along those lines:

```
Listener listener = new Listener()
{
    private boolean ignore = false;

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event e)
    {
        if(ignore)
            return;

        ignore = true;
        doPotentiallyCyclicStuff();
        ignore = false;
    }
};
```

It's not a very pretty solution, but it does work.

---

Looking forward to alternative solutions here, since this has been bothering me for a while now.

Comment: I have not seen anything better. In fact the TreeViewer code does exactly this to avoid cycles internally.

Comment: Who is updating ignore value in this case? It will always be false how come it reaches to doPotentiallyCyclicStuff(); ?

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande Read the if check again and think for a second ;)

Comment: @Baz got it mymistake